# Disable highcharts tooltip on certain lines, leave it enabled on others?

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highchart containing multiple lines.  I want to disable the tooltip on certain lines, and leave it enabled for others.  Is that possible?  I see how to disable the tooltip globally, but not by series.

For instance, on the [standard line chart example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/) is it possible to disable the tooltip on the red and blue lines but leave it enabled on the other two?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**UPDATE**

use [enableMouseTracking: Boolean](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking)

**Notice** `enableMouseTracking: Boolean` was introduced after this question was asked

**Old Answer**

I just Disabled the heights point in the `Tokyo`  series

here is your code

```js
         tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    
                    if(this.series.name == 'Tokyo' && this.y == 26.5 ){
                      return false ;
                    // to disable the tooltip at a point return false 
                    }else {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
                }   
                }
            }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bV6fT/)

Comment: Thanks very much, I have this working in my code now.  I found that setting 'enableMouseTracking: false' in the desired series also works. Cheers.

Comment: In my situation, i need to have click event on that particular series but not the tool tip. With enableMouseTracking : false option. Click event is also disabled. Hence I believe i should go with your Old Answer.

Comment: Is it possible to enable every tooltip again via click of a button with your code?

Comment: the documentation says you can set it per series but only provides an example of setting it globally

Comment: The link above to enableMouseTracking does not work. The question asks about enabling per series, but enableMouseTracking only seems to work for the entire chart. I wonder if this is broken in HighCharts (HighStock) 6?

Comment: This only sets it globally, not per series. I am unable to find any 'per series' `enableMouseTracking` setting. The first answer works better in this case.

Comment: So, if using the "pie" type of chart, returning false in the `pieFormatter` function still renders and empty tooltip when hovering over it. Not sure why returning false for this function is still rendering a tooltip, but need to disable a data point in a pie chart and can't see any way to do this!

Answer (score 54):

Use `enableMouseTracking`. It's the best way to do it.

**Per Serie**

```
series: [{
    name: 'Serie1',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
    enableMouseTracking: false
}, {
    name: 'Serie2',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 15.5, 15.2, 15.5, 15.2, 15.5, 11.3, 17.3, 11.9, 9.6]
}]
```

**Global**

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }
}
```

The code above will display tooltip for only the first serie.

Reference: [enableMouseTracking](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking)

Comment: It disables the drag and drop functionality as well.

Comment: How is this a functioning example? This does not work for me. `enableMouseTracking` is within `plotOptions` only. There is no `data` property inside of `plotOptions`.

Comment: @CodeAssist You can do it in `series` (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.enableMouseTracking) or `plotOptions` (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking)

Comment: @RicardoAlvaroLohmann for some reason I get an error stating the property doesn't exist. Looking at their example it still only uses it inside of the `plotOptions`. Have you actually done this? It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Figured it out. It was a @types/highchart issue because of the lack of typings for v6. Thanks

Comment: The singular of series is still series. "Per series" is effectively the same as "for a single series". No where in the highcharts documentation is a single series referred to as a 'serie'. This is not a thing in English or Highcharts. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23268/is-series-plural-or-singular

Comment: How to do this if using the "pie" type of chart?  Since multiple series just goes right on top of each other.  This method does not help in that case.

Answer (score 0):

For stock charts **enableMouseTracking: false** makes lines inactive on hover.

Here's better solution:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    type: 'column',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter: function() {
        return false
      }
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    type: 'column',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter: function() {
        return 'Second <strong>column</strong> series.'
      }
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    type: 'line',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter: function() {
        return false
      }
    }
  }]

});
```